# whats the easiest way to scrape a description tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make a 'recommend' button on my app that will go out and fetch the description tag for a given URL, and return it back. i was thinking of having this be a getScript() request to a certain controller (POST or GET?), then when the server returns a response the script inserts it into the text box

What is the easiest method to do this without all the overhead of something like nokogiri? this is the only place im scraping something in my whole app so id rather keep it to a very lightweight method.

Also, should I use GET or POST in my controller (according to the rails way)? Thanks!

Comment: you can also try nokogiri gem, which works on css path or xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By description do you mean the meta tag?

Let yahoos yql service do the heavy lifting for you.
e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="http://google.com" AND xpath="//head/meta"
```

[Here it is in their testing console](http://y.ahoo.it/ovzEM)

and [this is the url you would grab to retrieve the response in json](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url=%22http://google.com%22%20AND%20xpath=%22//head/meta%22&format=json)

Comment: Holy cow thats perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Quick Q, is this pulling this from cached yahoo results or it fetches it? what if its not in their database?

Comment: Yahoo scrapes it on the fly - it may serve up a cached result if you hit it on the same url too quickly.. but I have never had it issue being anything but a minute or so out.